# Tesla account not activated to trade or Transfer to trtransfer to anything and always come up as error message Can any one explain what is going on

Tags: transactions

How come I can’t get my Tesla out of this account?

GBYCRM2RBJGSD6DDSVRUSMZB4DIGPJUKGTKOVN6LE7QDTWSN2K2YFWXZ

Who do I contact to activate trading

Tod Troute

GCNB3NEKIRTJ5REJ3JOHC4ONGRFCFWWFTJX2DIMCYKFWXBCHZK5CCVAQ

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of scam assets in that account. There is not a tokenized Tesla share on Stellar, although DSTOQ may have offered one previously. Please take notice of all assets tagged as scams on LOBSTR, Stellar.expert, etc. They're there for a good reason.